# How can I run SQL statements on a named range within an excel sheet?

Tags: sql, vba, excel

All I am trying to do is take a standard range on an excel sheet (i.e. a named range, or even A1:F100), and run some sql queries on it, and return a recordset that I can either step through in VBA code, or even just paste into some other sheet in the same workbook.

Using ADODB was one thought, but how could I setup the connectionstring to point to some range within the current workbook?

I know before I have made use of the Microsoft query wizard, which was not ideal, but would work. I can't seem to get this to refer to a range within the sheet, only other excel files.

---

Here is the function I am left with. When I run it a few times my excel crashes with the usual out of resources error message. I have removed this function from my spreadsheet, and everything runs seamlessly multiple times, thus it is definitely caused by the code here.

I have cleaned up all the objects (correctly?). Does anyone have any ideas what could be going wrong? Could there be something in the connection string that could be tweaked, or could it be something to do with the variant that is returned from the GetRows method?

I am using MS ADO 2.8, and have also tried 2.5 with the same behaviour.

```
Function getTimeBuckets() As Collection

Dim strFile As String
Dim strCon As String
Dim strSQL As String
Dim dateRows As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim today As Date

Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
Set getTimeBuckets = New Collection

strFile = ThisWorkbook.FullName
strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & strFile _
    & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"
cn.Open strCon

strSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT(Expiration) FROM [PositionSummaryTable] where [Instrument Type] = 'LSTOPT'" 

rs.Open strSQL, cn


dateRows = rs.GetRows
rs.Close

'today = Date
today = "6-may-2009"

For i = 1 To UBound(dateRows, 2)
    If (dateRows(0, i) >= today) Then
        getTimeBuckets.Add (dateRows(0, i))
    End If
Next i

Set dateRows = Nothing
Set cn = Nothing
Set rs = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can just use the name.

```
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset 

strFile = Workbooks(1).FullName
strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & strFile _
    & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

cn.Open strCon

''Pick one:
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM DataTable" ''Named range
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$A1:E346]" ''Range

rs.Open strSQL, cn

Debug.Print rs.GetString
```

**In response to question part 2**

I notice that you only want today's records, so you should be able to modify the sql to:

```
strSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT(Expiration) FROM [PositionSummaryTable] " _
& "where [Instrument Type] = 'LSTOPT' AND [Expiration]=#" _
& Format(Date(),"yyyy/mm/dd") & "#"
```

You have not closed the connection:

```
cn.Close
```

And then

```
 Set rs=Nothing
 Set cn=Nothing
```

Comment: Thanks, works great. I must have had something else wrong (see above comment), which made me think you had to do something different with the connection string.

Comment: You can run into problems with ADO if you have not saved.

Comment: It all works perfectly, but there is some kind of memory leak going on.

I will post the function below as it's too long for the comment.

Comment: Even afer closing the connection, that function still holds on to a large chunk of memory. There is no way to force garbage collection in VBA like there is in C# is there? (i doubt this will work anyway, but it would be worth a try) It is definitely wanting to old on to some object in that function :(

Comment: Looking at the task manager, it is definitely the call rs.Open which is grabbing the memory, and never letting go.

Comment: There is a KB: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319998 BUG: Memory leak occurs when you query an open Excel worksheet by using ActiveX Data Objects (ADO)

Comment: Thanks! At least I know now I'm not doing something stupid. I kinda gave ADO to much credit thinking: "There can't possibly be such a large bug in here, everyone uses ADO." But I suppose not many people use it to refer to an open file... Thanks again for all the help :).

Comment: Thanks!  Now, how can I work in a WHERE clause?  Can we do updates?

Comment: Also would like to know about using a named range in a where clause.

Answer (score 1):

How about using of LIKE clause?

I tried to use:

```
select * from [PES$] where PID_TAG like '*5400001'
```

without success....

this works:

```
select * from [PES$] where PID_TAG = 'PIT5400001'
```

but this is not I want.

**EDIT**

hummm.... we need to change wildcards to work... 
don't use *, use %

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about VBA, but there are code online in Delphi and C# that uses the format

```
SELECT * FROM [SheetName$A1:B2]
```

Have you tried it?

Comment: how would you execute a statement like this in VBA?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using powershell, $ is an internal character. use `$

eg:

```
"Select * from [VM`$A3:F30]"
```