# VBA ActiveWorkbook / RefersToLocal - 1004 Application defined or object defined error

Tags: vba, excel

When executing the following line, the 1004 runtime error (Application defined or object defined error) is thrown

```
rangeString = ActiveWorkbook.Names.Item("MyTableName").RefersToLocal
```

I cant see anything wrong with my code, and the table name appears to be correct. This code is inside a class module and I am not a vba expert, so I dont know if that introduces any issues with scope etc.

Comment: Try this `rangeString = ThisWorkbook.Names.Item("MyTableName").RefersToLocal`

Comment: Same problem, unfortunately

Comment: show us the code, it's possible though that `MyTableName` is not a range name

Comment: Or upload your workbook in any free file sharing site and share the link here

Comment: It isn't strictly a range name, as it is a table name, I'm following the logic from this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/19755989

Comment: See http://i.imgur.com/66LLQYB.jpg for details

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your object (MyTableName) is an Excel data table, use the Range used by the ListObject, e.g.

```
Sub test()
    Dim L As ListObject

    Set L = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("MyTableName")
    ' at this point you can inspect the properties of L in the debugger

    ' retrieve the local address of tue underlying range
    Debug.Print L.Range.AddressLocal

End Sub
```

Comment: + 1 You beat me to it :D I had to discard my post :) I had a slightly different variation `"=" & oSh.Name & "!" & oLo.Range.Address`

Comment: @SiddharthRout it's not easy to beat you ... I'm honoured

Comment: Having said that, how do I get the sheet name out?

Comment: @NeilP welcome ... looking forward to many more cool questions and answers

Comment: Neil, I already showed how to get the sheet name in my first comment above.

Comment: `L.Parent.Name` works as well ... this is the link to Siddharts `oSh.ListObjects` as a ListObject is a child of a sheet ... so with the L.Range you can treat it like a range, the ListObject itself gives you a couple of nice properties and methods to play with

Answer (score 5):

**Please do not select this as an answer.** This is only for value add :)

If you just have the name of the table and are not sure which sheet the table is in then you can try this

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim oSh As Worksheet
    Dim oLo As ListObject

    For Each oSh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each oLo In oSh.ListObjects
            If oLo.Name = "MyTableName" Then
                Debug.Print "=" & oSh.Name & "!" & oLo.Range.Address
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: @SiddhartRout You've helped me yet again, I thought I'd intrude on this quickly to thank you for a few answers on this site that have been invaluable! I'm 3 weeks in a new job writing VBA for the first time, and things like this are just brilliant!

Answer (score 5):

I think *Range Object* can access any table at any sheet just fine:

```
Debug.Print "=" & Range("MyTableName").Parent.Name & "!" & Range("MyTableName").Address
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone up against similar errors try this one-liner in the immediate window :

`For ii = 1 to ThisWorkbook.Names.Count : ? ii & " " & ThisWorkbook.Names.Item(ii).Name : next`

and from the results you may find that the sheet name is part of the name i.e. `'My Second Sheet'!Print_Area'` - this full name needs to be used as the index to `.Names` :

`? ThisWorkbook.Names.Item("'BlahBlah'!Print_Area").RefersTo`