# Excel UDF to return array from ACE SQL recordset

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am trying to use ACE sql to return array from recordset. The  function works well with table ranges.

**Problem:** the function  returns the right number of records if the query returns 2 or more records. However if only one record is found, all rows are filled repetitively with this one row. This is wrong but I cannot find the reason why.

In addition, I wish my function would return column names from Recordset. I have no idea how to glue it together with the array returned from recordset.

Here is the code, credits are due to the author of another solution that I am trying to adapt to my needs:  [Performing SQL queries on an Excel Table within a Workbook with VBA Macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19755396/performing-sql-queries-on-an-excel-table-within-a-workbook-with-vba-macro/28879494#28879494)

```
Function SQL(dataRange As Range, CritA As String) As Variant
Application.Volatile

Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim currAddress As String

currAddress = ActiveSheet.Name & "$" & dataRange.Address(False, False)

strFile = ThisWorkbook.FullName
strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strFile _
& ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

cn.Open strCon


strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [" & currAddress & "]" & _
         "WHERE [A] =  '" & CritA & "'  " & _
         "ORDER BY 1 ASC"

rs.Open strSQL, cn

'SQL = rs.GetString
SQL = Application.Transpose(rs.GetRows)


Set rs = Nothing
Set cn = Nothing



End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the field names, you will have to loop through the array from the recordset too:

```
With rs
    If Not .EOF Then
        vData = .getrows()

        ReDim vDataOut(LBound(vData, 2) To UBound(vData, 2) + 1, LBound(vData, 1) To UBound(vData, 1))
        ' get headers
        For i = 1 To .Fields.Count
            vDataOut(0, i - 1) = .Fields(i - 1).Name
        Next i
        ' Copy data
        For x = LBound(vData, 2) To UBound(vData, 2)
            For y = LBound(vData, 1) To UBound(vData, 1)
                vDataOut(x + 1, y) = vData(y, x)
            Next y
        Next x
    End If
End With
```

for example.

Comment: Thank you very much, Rory. It is great! will try it out.