# Using Slicers/Filters in a Table

Tags: excel

Example I will be using is a list of people who I buy sweets off, tabled into preference and sortable by category. I have a table of values in the format:

```
Option 1|Option 2|Option 3|Catagory 1 | Category 2 |
--------|--------|--------|-----------|------------|
Bob     |  Mary  | Jane   | Candy     | Sherbert   |
James   |  Bob   | Jane   | Choc      | Cadbury Bar|
Jane    |        |        | Candy     | Haribo     |
Jane    |  Mary  | James  | Candy     | Millions   |
...     | ...    | ...    | ...       | ...        |
```

I want to be able to use dropdown boxes or slicers to pick the name and first category and show a filtered list of the final category (2) and the "rank" based on them being primary, secondary or tertiary option, for example as I select Jane:

```
Name |^| Catagory 1|^| Category 2 | Rank  |
-------|-------------|------------|-------|
 Jane  | Candy       | Sherbert   | 3     |
                     | Haribo     | 1     |
                     | Millions   | 1     |
```

or:

```
Name |^| Catagory 1|^| Category 2 | Rank  |
-------|-------------|------------|-------|
 Jane  | Choc        | Cadbury Bar| 3     |
```

(depending on how it is picked)

**Comment Questions:**

- What Excel version are you using? **2013**
- Is this no-vba task? **Preferably no-vba, if you chose to answer in VBA please consider that it needs to be tailored to explaining how to implement the solution to someone with limited excel-vba experience.**
- Can you use two tables (1 input, 1 output) or you want the layout to change dynamically? **Using 2 tables is fine, feel free to impress by using dynamic tables if you so wish (dynamic tables may win the bounty over an answer without them)**
- Can you explain how field Rank is calculated? For example Rank=3 in case of Jane | Choc | Cadbury Bar ? **In the row for Cadbury bar, Jane is the 3rd option, hence rank 3. If she was second she would be rank 2 or if first, rank 1.**
- You have Name (Jane) in the first three columns. May the same Name (Jane) appear in any of the three columns? Can you explain the reason of having names in three columns? If the name may appear in any of the column then they have to be unique - is that so? **Consider the data as lines first, perhaps reading right-to-left may help. The *Category 2* column is the only column that contains unique values. Any name can appear any number of times in the first 3 columns but none of the names can be duplicated in the same row: Jane cannot be the option 1, 2 and 3 for a single item (for example)**

Comment: What Excel version are you using? Is this no-vba task? Also Jane, not Mary. Can you use two tables (1 input, 1 output) or you want the layout to change dynamically?

Comment: I have answered in the question.

Comment: Can you explain how field Rank is calculated? For example Rank=3 in case of `Jane | Choc | Cadbury Bar` ?

Comment: You have Name (Jane) in the first three columns. May the same Name (Jane) appear in any of the three columns? Can you explain the reason of having names in three columns? If the name may appear in any of the column then they have to be unique - is that so?

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin answered in question.

Comment: How is the data fed into the system? You manually append the table or it's linked to some external saurce, e.g. SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a VBA solution which uses standard Excel components

Your workbook should have two sheets named `SourceData` and `Calculation` with two tables having the same names as in pictures below:

[image]
[image]

Now add VBA code that will process your data. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to open the code editor. Add a new module:

[image]

Now in that module insert this code:

```
Const SOURCE_DATA_SHEET As String = "SourceData"
Const SOURCE_DATA_TABLE As String = "SourceData"

Const CALCULATION_SHEET As String = "Calculation"
Const CALCULATION_TABLE As String = "Calculation"

Const S_OPTION_1 As Integer = 1
Const S_OPTION_2 As Integer = 2
Const S_OPTION_3 As Integer = 3
Const S_CATEGORY_1 As Integer = 4
Const S_CATEGORY_2 As Integer = 5

Const C_WIDTH As Integer = 4

Const C_NAME As Integer = 1
Const C_CATEGORY_1 As Integer = 2
Const C_CATEGORY_2 As Integer = 3
Const C_RANK As Integer = 4

Function GetTable(sheetName As String, tableName As String) As ListObject
    Set GetTable = Worksheets(sheetName).ListObjects(tableName)
End Function

Sub ClearTable(dataTable As ListObject)
    dataTable.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    dataTable.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    If dataTable.ListRows.Count >= 1 Then
        dataTable.DataBodyRange.Delete
    End If
End Sub

Sub InsertRow(ByRef dataTable As ListObject, ByRef dataRow As Variant)
    dataTable.ListRows.Add
    dataTable.ListRows(dataTable.ListRows.Count).Range = dataRow
End Sub

Sub CalculateRanks(ByRef dataTable As ListObject, ByRef destinationTable As ListObject)
    Dim newRow(1 To C_WIDTH) As Variant
    Dim nameValue As Variant

    For Each dataRow In dataTable.ListRows
        With dataRow
            newRow(C_CATEGORY_1) = .Range(S_CATEGORY_1).Value
            newRow(C_CATEGORY_2) = .Range(S_CATEGORY_2).Value

            For Each optionNumber In Array(S_OPTION_1, S_OPTION_2, S_OPTION_3)
                nameValue = .Range(optionNumber).Value
                If nameValue <> "" Then
                    newRow(C_NAME) = nameValue
                    newRow(C_RANK) = optionNumber
                    InsertRow destinationTable, newRow
                End If
            Next optionNumber

        End With
    Next dataRow
End Sub

Sub Main()
    Dim sourceTable As ListObject
    Dim destinationTable As ListObject
    Set sourceTable = GetTable(SOURCE_DATA_SHEET, SOURCE_DATA_TABLE)
    Set destinationTable = GetTable(CALCULATION_SHEET, CALCULATION_TABLE)
    ClearTable destinationTable
    CalculateRanks sourceTable, destinationTable
End Sub
```

On your `Calculation` sheet, add a button that you will use to run the code. Under "Developer" tab (if you don't see this tab, go to Excel Options / Customize Ribbon / Check the "Developer" checkbox in "Main Tabs" list) insert a button form control:

[image]

And link your macro `Main` to the button:

[image]

You're done! Now every time you click the button, the `Calculation` table will get refreshed. You may use filters to show the desired content.

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with using SQL statements in Excel, it is very easy. You can use the approach I presented here [Filter ShowDetails of PivotTable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33807584/1903793). If you are not, do not worry, just [download my file](https://docs.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=0B3TGVycQLkZ_UXVTRFI1TTRkbmc&export=download), feed your table and use it.

The idea in SQL is:

```
Select Name=[Option 1],[Category 1],[Category 2],Rank=1 union all
Select Name=[Option 2],[Category 1],[Category 2],Rank=2 union all
Select Name=[Option 3],[Category 1],[Category 2],Rank=3
```

* I changed the headings for using SQL statements in Excel does not allow column names ending with numbers - stupid bug learnt the hard way.

It produces the following output table:

[image]

With such an output table the following part is very easy. You do not even need slicers. Just use filters of the table to get the desired results:

[image]

You might be willing to have your output table without rows which do not contain names (i.e. row 7 or 11). Then simply use SQL clause:

```
WHERE Name is not null
```

You can adjust this code so that the output table generates automatically on file open.

Comment: I won't be giving the bounty to this but I really liked your answer, the effort you put into explaining it and the example file you gave. I have given the points to the similar implementation by @Taosique because I feel that as a beginner I have learnt more implementing his solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here's your dynamic table, no VBA solution. You just need to add a single helper column.

First, pick some sort of delimiter. I chose "!". .

Next, in an adjacent column put the following big honking formula:

```
[Name of person]|
----------------|
=IFERROR(LEN(LEFT(CONCATENATE("!",A2,"!",B2,"!",C2,"!"),FIND(CONCATENATE("!",$F$1,"!"),CONCATENATE("!",A2,"!",B2,"!",C2,"!"))-1))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(CONCATENATE("!",A2,"!",B2,"!",C2,"!"),FIND(CONCATENATE("!",$F$1,"!"),CONCATENATE("!",A2,"!",B2,"!",C2,"!"))-1),"!",""))+1,"")|
...|
```

What this does is tell you how many exclamation points occurred in the concatenated list of names before the value in F1 (which, in my workbook is the column header where I put "Jane"). (It then adds one, so that the top spot is "1", and not "0"). If the name in the header row is not found, the cell is left blank.

Once you've got this in place, your process for getting your filtered list is:

*1. Enter the name of the person in F1.*

*2. Filter out blanks from F1.*

*3. Filter Category 1 as desired.*

Note that in my formulas, the columns match up as follows:

```
Col A  |Col B  |Col C  |Col D    |Col E    |Col F           |
Option1|Option2|Option3|Category1|Category2|[Name of person]|
```

These formulas produce the following output:

```
Option 1|Option 2|Option 3|Category 1 | Category 2 |Jane |
--------|--------|--------|-----------|------------|-----|
Bob     |  Mary  | Jane   | Candy     | Sherbert   |3    |
James   |  Bob   | Jane   | Choc      | Cadbury Bar|3    |
Jane    |        |        | Candy     | Haribo     |1    |
Jane    |  Mary  | James  | Candy     | Millions   |1    |
...     | ...    | ...    | ...       | ...        |...  |
```

Or, for James...

```
Option 1|Option 2|Option 3|Category 1 | Category 2 |James |
--------|--------|--------|-----------|------------|----- |
Bob     |  Mary  | Jane   | Candy     | Sherbert   |      |
James   |  Bob   | Jane   | Choc      | Cadbury Bar|1     |
Jane    |        |        | Candy     | Haribo     |      |
Jane    |  Mary  | James  | Candy     | Millions   |3     |
...     | ...    | ...    | ...       | ...        |...   |
```

Comment: Thank you for your concise and well formatted answer, I really appreciate it!