# DELETE from ListObject table rows meeting condition using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, delete-row, listobject

Is it possible in VBA to DELETE all the rows meeting condition from Excel ListObject table? I am looking for something similar to SQL statement:

`DELETE FROM MyListObjectTable WHERE MyColumn='Some Condition'`

Comment: Is it connected to a source? Do you want to delete them from the source?  If not I'd use the condition <> in the sql for the table.   Have you tried anything?

Comment: It it connected to SQL, however I can break that connection, if necessary. I tried to make it through ADO Connection similar to the idea you can find here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33807584/1903793

Comment: use the `listobject.querytable.connection` to create the ado and `execute` the sql you have, then refresh the table.

Comment: if some condition exists in C3 then Set listObj = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1") -next line -
listObj.ListRows(3).Delete

Comment: @JohnMuggins I have a huge table. I would like make bulk deletes, not single or looplike. Better from your proposal would be deleting with auto-filter. However SQL-like statements are much more superior for the sake of clarity.

Comment: Do SQL statements work in VBA?  If it were me I'd use a range.find method to find each condition in the column and save that row to an array.  Then transpose the array in descending order and delete the rows with a for statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

.- Break the connection,

.- Sort the `ListObject` as per condition (Optional just to have the results of  the condition in one `Range.Area` for the deletion),

.- `AutoFilter` the `ListObject` as per condition,

.- Delete visible rows of the `ListObject.DataBodyRange`

.- Clear `AutoFilter`