# OLEDB query to fetch all column except few exceptional columns

Tags: excel, vb.net, oledb

I'm trying to read excel data into datatable object.But, some columns in excel is has corrupted data specifically of type **DATE** .

[image: excel:]

I'm using VB code to read the data with

1. OLEDB Connection

   ```
   dtData = objExcelReader.ReadWorksheet(strFilePath.ToString, "select * from sheet1$", True)
   ```

With this code I get '**Not a legal OleAut date**' error.

2. With ExcelReader,

   ```
   objExcelReader = New ExcelIO.ExcelReader
   objExcelReader.UseHeaders = True
   objExcelReader.AllowSpacesInColumnName = blnAllowSpacesInColumnName
   objExcelReader.ReadFormatting = True
   objExcelReader.TrimStrings = True
   objExcelReader.ClearColumnDatatypes()    
   objExcelReader.DefaultStartRow = intStartRow
   dtData = objExcelReader.Read(strFilePath.ToString, thisApplication, strInputSheetName)
   ```

I get exception  - '**Out of present range. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002000A (DISP_E_OVERFLOW))**'

3. Using range in query, I'm able to fetch records. I need to include multiple range in that case.

   ```
   dtData = objExcelReader.ReadWorksheet(strFilePath.ToString, "select * from sheet1$O:AK", True)
   ```

Can someone help me to include multiple range here like **A:K & O:AK**

Or to fix any of above mentioned issues and ignore those exceptional column.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try not to put column containing dates in the first column of table.
2. Sort data in that way that
   data column has data (with proper data format) in the fist row.
3. See more on corrupt data formats here:
   https://dutchgemini.wordpress.com/2011/04/21/two-serious-flaws-with-excels-copyfromrecordset-method/
4. Check this out how I have overcome corrupt formatting in open recordset.
   https://stackoverflow.com/a/33807584/1903793