# VBA Joining arrays as if they were relational database tables

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have two arrays in my VBA code at the moment.  They are structured very much like a database table except they are horizontal, so the first three rows (of 7) effectively determine the primary key within the array.

I'd like to perform OUTER and INNER join operations on them as if they were database tables.  That would allow me to easily compare values, check for missing values, etc.

I could do this by iterating through one of them and matching it against the other (and it would totally work), but I'm trying to find something that's more suited to large bulk operations and less of an iterative process.

Is there perhaps an Intersect or Union operation that makes this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you doing this in Excel instead of in a relational database program?

Comment: This is not part of a regular process.  It's kind of an ad-hoc request.  the data is not coming from a database, I'm basically parsing csv files to pull it into the array I mentioned.

There are lots of ways I could solve this without doing what I am asking about (build DB tables for the datasets, use a Python script, etc).  I just already have some VBA code that gets the stuff into the arrays and I'd like to not rewrite that.  I also am just generally curious if this can be done in VBA,

Comment: You could write the arrays to a worksheet and then perform the SQL queries.  See [Performing SQL queries on an Excel Table within a Workbook with VBA Macro](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19755396/performing-sql-queries-on-an-excel-table-within-a-workbook-with-vba-macro)

Comment: Unfortunately I can't think of any other way to perform the queries.  There is no way to directly SQL query VBA arrays :(

Comment: This appears to show a way to use SQL directly against Excel: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/147331/Reading-Excel-file-in-SQL-Server

Comment: I've been looking into this myself over the last few days, wound up doing something similar to what tigeravatar linked above.  I'm considering moving to something like [copying the array to an ADO recordset](http://excelexperts.com/Array-To-ADO-Recordset) but haven't tried yet.

Comment: Instead of parsing the .csv files, connect to them with the [Microsoft ODBC Text Driver](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/850320).  You can use SQL directly on the .csvs.