# Query MS Excel Table using SQL

Tags: sql, vba, excel, ado

I found this code to use sql to query a MS Excel table. However, when I run it I get a message stating that the object "Sheet5$" could not be found. There is a table called "Table" on Sheet 5 of the workbook that I am running the code on.

How can I get this code to work

```
'Reference: Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects x.x Library
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

'Not the best way to refer to a workbook, but convenient for
'testing. it is probably best to refer to the workbook by name.
strFile = ActiveWorkbook.FullName

'Connection string for 2007/2010
strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strFile _
         & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 xml;HDR=Yes;"";"

cn.Open strCon


'SQL query string
sSQL = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet5$]"
rs.Open sSQL, cn
```

Comment: Possible duplicated of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19755396/performing-sql-queries-on-an-excel-table-within-a-workbook-with-vba-macro

Comment: Have you ran a debug.print on your strCon?  And checked to make sure your connection was opened?

Comment: Use the exact name of your sheet. If there are spaces in the name include those too.

Comment: ^ what this dude said. It happens in VBA too, so its something you'd need to know eventually