# Query Large Excel File using VBA/SQL

Tags: sql, vba, excel

I am trying to write some SQL code within VBA to execute a query on a relatively large excel file(500,000 lines), where I would like to find the total sales for these given subcategories:

My data looks like this:

```
Order ID|Sales|ProductSubCategory|Region
234324   3400  BookCases          South 
234345   2700  Tables             North
```

This is the main criteria for the SQL Query:

- Bookcases Chairs
- Chairmats
- Office Furnishings
- Tables

I am relatively new to using VBA, and especially SQL within VBA, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Comment: There are plenty of posts here on SO covering using SQL to query Excel data.  Take a look at those, try out some code, then post back with specific questions you might have.  E.g.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19755396/performing-sql-queries-on-an-excel-table-within-a-workbook-with-vba-macro

Comment: Curious, why are you storing such volume of data in Excel and not use an actual database? If using Windows, the Jet/ACE SQL engine (the default database of MS Access) is already installed and available to use.

Comment: I don't have access to the database, just a file with the data from the database. Think something like this is what I need: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1xIZUZaJB8s

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Power query** to import the relevant data only (using filter conditions ) from excel file/ Sql database to the **data model** in new excel file and then you can perform analysis on that data model easily.

Answer (score 0):

```
strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" _
               & "Data Source='C:\Path\To\Workbook.xlsm';" _
               & "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;"";"

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]"
```

You can treat excel files like data sources like you would an access file, and query it that way :)

Comment: Thanks! I was looking at a video earlier, and I was told that the query returns a recordset, or the results of the query. How would I store that in a new sheet?

Comment: well it depends on how your calling upon the recordset. But generally you could use something like ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetXYZ").Range("a1").CopyFromRecordSet

Comment: @petergensler here check this for more info http://www.functionx.com/vbaccess/Lesson22.htm

Comment: just an update...found out that if you can set up a connection to the workbook properly, then you really don't need to touch VBA at all, and can use the microsoft query wizard to write sql, which is almost the same interface as the access query interface.

Comment: yeah it definitely is not the prettiest SQL, but I think it gets the job done. surprised that there is barely anything on the web about using this to query large spreadsheets, as it's definitely old school but better than using 5 filters at once.

Comment: @petergensler i would get good at writing the SQL against the sheet. Friend of mine says he has to results to various methods to extract data depending on the portal he is working out of. You may not always have the luxury of the "plug and play" method

Comment: Yeah one of the limitations I've seen so far is that the data really has to be "tidy" to work with, or it needs to be in a named range called Database, and you cannot have any records with blank data. pretty hard to tidy up messy data in excel. Personally, I'd prefer to use a tool like R to create a SQL query, but I don't have access to that in my working environment.

Answer (score 0):

RunQuery(SourceFile As String, Targetrange As Range, strsql As String, ColName As Boolean)

```
Dim dbConnection As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim dbConnectionString As String
Dim TargetCell As Range, i As Integer

dbConnectionString = "Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)}; DBQ=" & SourceFile & ";"

Set dbConnection = New ADODB.Connection
'On Error GoTo InvalidInput
dbConnection.Open dbConnectionString

Set rs = dbConnection.Execute(strsql)
If ColName Then
    Set TargetCell = Targetrange.Cells(1, 1)
    For i = 0 To rs.Fields.count - 1
        TargetCell.Offset(0, i).Formula = rs.Fields(i).Name
        Debug.Print rs.Fields(i).Name
    Next i
    Set TargetCell = Targetrange.Offset(1, 0)
Else
    Set TargetCell = Targetrange.Offset(0, 0)
End If
TargetCell.CopyFromRecordset rs
rs.Close
dbConnection.Close
Set TargetCell = Nothing
Set rs = Nothing
Set dbConnection = Nothing
```