# query excel with sql

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access

Using MS Office+VBA (or, sometimes, Visual Studio 2010) I am looking for a way to query Excel-Files using **only** SQL Query, similar to this way of querying a textfile:

```
SELECT * FROM [Text;DATABASE=L:\Testfiles].test1.csv
```

As a result I would expect something like:

```
SELECT * FROM [Excel File=L:\Testfiles\test2.xls].[sheet1$A1:B1000]
```

I am **not** looking for a way to query Excel-Files with SQL and a ADODB-connection string (as depicted on [connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/) or [here on so.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19755396/performing-sql-queries-on-an-excel-table-within-a-workbook-with-vba-macro)), since I want all information regarding the data source inside the actual SQL-Code, and not split up between SQL and the connection setup in VB/VBA.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Regards
Martin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `FROM` clause like this:

```
FROM [sheet1$A3:E22] IN 'C:\path\MyFile.xlsx' [Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=0]
```

Comment: Excellent. I know I saw something like that before.
Many thanks Sergey!

Comment: Works perfectly in an Access query