# Error while executing UPDATE within Excel Workbook

Tags: excel, excel-2007, adodb, vba

In the code below I was testing how to update data in a tab in the current Excel workbook.
The select statement works.
The update statement does not work. It produces error with:

```
Run-time error -2147457259 
The Microsoft Office Access engine stopped the process because you and another user are attempting to change the same data at the same time.
```

The VBA macro is within the same workbook that contains the data.
Would this be the problem?
Thanks.

```
Option Explicit

 Global cn As Object, rs As Object, output As String, sql As String
Sub MainLogic()
    Call DB_Connect
    Call DB_Select
    Call DB_Disconnect

    Call DB_Connect
    Call DB_Update
    Call DB_Disconnect

End Sub
Sub DB_Connect()
   Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
   With cn
        .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
        .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name & ";" & _
        "Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;READONLY=FALSE';"

        .Open
    End With

End Sub
Sub DB_Disconnect()
    rs.Close
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
    Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
Sub DB_Select()

    sql = "SELECT * FROM [Trans$]" & " WHERE BrkrID='Brkr C' and TransStatus =1 And Transtype='Fund'"
    Set rs = cn.Execute(sql)
    Do
       output = rs(0) & ";" & rs(1) & ";" & rs(2) & ";" & rs(3) & ";" & rs(4) & ";" & rs(5) & ";" & rs(6) & ";" & rs(7)
       Debug.Print output
       rs.MoveNext
    Loop Until rs.EOF
End Sub

Sub DB_Update()

    sql = "Update [Trans$] Set TransStatus = 2;" '<-- Porblem is here
    Set rs = cn.Execute(sql)

End Sub
```

Comment: I think there is another method to be used when you need to extract from same WB. Ill dig around for it, but i recall seeing this when I was having issues with writing sql against excel files

Comment: Also nice code structure btw. :D

Comment: I this this on SO is relevant to your interest http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19755396/performing-sql-queries-on-an-excel-table-within-a-workbook-with-vba-macro

Comment: @DougCoats, thank you for you comments and being willing to help. The link you have provided is not addressing the update issue. It is strange that the connection string does not provide a parameter for shared access. If you find anything pls let me know. Thanks.