# Highlighting differences between duplicates in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I have a spreadsheet with the following columns :

```
Transaction_ID  counter State   File_Date   Date_of_Service Claim_Status    NDC_9   Drug_Name   Manufacturer    Quantity    Original_Patient_Pay_Amount Patient_Out_of_Pocket   eVoucher_Amount WAC_per_Unit__most_recent_  RelayHealth_Admin_Fee   Total_Voucher_Charge    Raw_File_Name
```

There are duplicate transaction ID's here. Is there VBA that would highlight where there are differences between two rows? So there may be data with the same Transaction ID but I want to highlight where they may have other fields that are different, therefore they aren't truly duplicates and would like to see what information is different.

thanks!

Comment: Add a column to concatenate all columns that make up your "unique key", and then *conditional formatting -> highlight duplicates* on that column.

Comment: Perhaps SQL via ADO, grouping by ID.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19755396/performing-sql-queries-on-an-excel-table-within-a-workbook-with-vba-macro.  It can also be done via an array formula

Comment: Does it have to be VBA or would a simple function in a new column suffice?

Comment: There is a lot of ambiguity in how you've asked this question.  e.g. Is the data set sorted in any particular way?  That will greatly simplify or complicate the answer.

Comment: Mat's Mug concat + conditional format worked perfectly,thanks so much that's exactly what I needed!

Comment: How does that give you column-specific highlighting.. to "see what information is different"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel's *find duplicates* conditional format should suffice for this. The problem is that it only works well off one column.

> *So there may be data with the same Transaction ID but I want to highlight where they may have other fields that are different, therefore they aren't truly duplicates*

So instead of tracking duplicates in the *Transaction ID* column alone, you can try adding a new column and, in that new column, concatenate all the columns for which the combined values *should* be unique - and then run Excel's *find duplicates* conditional format on *that* column.

For example if the combination of [Transaction_ID], [File_Date] and [NDC_9] should be unique, make a new column that combines [Transaction_ID], [File_Date] and [NDC_9] column values - assuming your data is in an actual *table* you could have a table formula like so:

```
=[@Transaction_ID]&[@File_Date]&[@NDC_9]
```

> *and would like to see what information is different.*

You can then filter the dupes in that column, and then, looking at the other columns you can see how they are different. It's not really possible to be any more specific than that with the way you've worded your question...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

1. It's an unsorted dataset
2. column 1 contains the repeatable ID
3. the first row contains headers

...the following code (in the SHeet's module) will turn any cell yellow that has a value that is totally unique for the ID that appears in the leftmost column...

```
    Option Explicit

    Public Sub HighlightUniqueValues()

        Dim r As Long, c As Long  'row and column counters
        Dim LastCol As Long, LastRow As Long 'right-most and bottom-most column and row
        Dim ColLetter As String
        Dim RepeatValues As Long

        'get right-most used column
        LastCol = Me.Cells(1, Me.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        'get bottom-most used row
        LastRow = Me.Cells(Me.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        'assume first column has the main ID
        For r = 2 To LastRow 'skip the top row, which presumably holds the column headers
            For c = 2 To LastCol 'skip the left-most column, which should contain the ID
                'Get column letter
                ColLetter = Split(Cells(1, c).Address(True, False), "$")(0)

                '   Count the number of repeat values in the current
                'column associated with the same value in the
                'left-most column
                RepeatValues = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("A:A"), Range("A" & r), Range(ColLetter & ":" & ColLetter), Range(ColLetter & r))

                '   If there is only one instance, then it's a lone
                'value (unique for that ID) and should be highlighted
                If RepeatValues = 1 Then
                    Range(ColLetter & r).Interior.ColorIndex = 6 'yellow background
                Else
                    Range(ColLetter & r).Interior.ColorIndex = 0 'white background
                End If
            Next c
        Next r

    End Sub
```

e.g...[image]