# Combine data from one table to another table at multiple level

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I have following table in sheet1.

```
Project| Resource Name | Line Manager
----------------------------------

2345    David          Peter
2345    Tam        Peter
2345    Richard        Peter
2358    Russell        Adam
```

Sheet2 Has following table

```
Project| Month |Revenue
-----------------------

2345    Jan 10000
2345    Feb 15000
2358    Jan 8000
2358    Feb 12000
```

how to get the following result in sheet2

```
Project| Month| Revenue| Resource|Name Line Manager
------------------------------------------------

2345    Jan 10000   David   Peter
2345    Jan 10000   Tam Peter
2345    Jan 10000   Richard Peter
2345    Feb 15000   David   Peter
2345    Feb 15000   Tam Peter
2345    Feb 15000   Richard Peter
2358    Jan 8000    Russell Adam
2358    Feb 12000   Russell Adam
```

Comment: how about: select s1.*, s2.* from sheet1 s1 join sheet2 s2 on s2.project=s1.project

Comment: @xeo Looks like an answer... Post answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about:

```
select s1.*, s2.* from sheet1 s1 join sheet2 s2 on s2.project=s1.project
```

Comment: thanks for the input. would it be possible to achieve this via VBA excel?

Comment: @user3200076 The answer is yes and the solution (for this new question) is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19755396/performing-sql-queries-on-an-excel-table-within-a-workbook-with-vba-macro