# Excel VBA Array, add up columns where another column is the same value

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have a large table of 6 columns.
I have an array of the table created:

```
 myArray = Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange.value
```

I now need to add up the values in column 6 where the value in column 2 is 7.

I know this would be much easier in SQL but don't have access to it unfortunately (or Access).

I have several different values in column 2 and need to do this for each group of distinct values.

Comment: You can actually query the table like a database, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19755396/performing-sql-queries-on-an-excel-table-within-a-workbook-with-vba-macro)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
Function MyFunc() As Integer
    MyFunc = 0
    For i = 1 To 999
        If Cells(i, 2).Value = 7 Then
            MyFunc = MyFunc + Cells(i, 7).Value
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Change 999 to the number of rows you're iterating over, and get the sum value like this:

```
Dim Sum As Integer
Sum = MyFunc
```

Answer (score 0):

`SUMIF` function would help you out with this,

I am having the below formula in cell `G1` which gives the total of `column F` which has a corresponding 7 in `column B`,

```
=SUMIF(B:B,7,F:F)
```

[image]

If you want this only with vba, then here is the same function in vba,

```
Sub sumCols()
Range("G1") = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Range("B:B"), 7, Range("F:F"))
End Sub
```

You could change that `7` dynamically if you want.