# Pull Only One Unique Item from Column of Dupes Based on Another Cell

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have a sheet that looks like this:

[image: Sample]

I have VBA code that launches an email and takes data from the sheet and puts it in the email body based on an inputbox value that is searched for in the sheet.  Values are grabbed from the row based on finding that value.  What I am having trouble with now is we have many dupes and I want to pull a name only once, and then getting it to loop, creating a new email when it hits a new approver name, then grabbing all of *that* approver's customers, and so on.

Example from above sheet:
Email says 'Dear Chris, 
Your customers Thomas, Mark, and Jared all need to be reviewed."

So I need code that gets all customers (column C) assigned to one approver (column E), but only grabs one instance of each customer name.

Then, it creates a new separate email when it finds the next approver, in this case John. So the approver name becomes a delimiter.

I am unsure how to do this, or what is even the best approach.  Can anyone offer up any ideas?  I am learning, but this part is giving me trouble.
Here is the code I have so far:

```
Sub Test()
Dim aOutlook As Object
Dim aEmail As Object
Dim rngeAddresses As Range, rngeCell As Range, strRecipients As String
Dim strbox As String
Dim stritem As String
Dim x As Long
Dim r As Long
Dim lr, lookRng As Range
Dim findStr As String
Dim foundCell As Variant
Dim foundcell1 As Variant
Dim foundcell2 As Variant
Dim strbody As String
Dim sigstring As String
Dim signature As String
Dim findstr1 As String
Dim foundrng As Range
Dim valuefound As Boolean
Dim strFilename As String

Set aOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set aEmail = aOutlook.CreateItem(0)

'Input box(es)

findStr = InputBox("Enter approver name to find")

'Greeting based on time of day

Select Case Time
       Case 0.25 To 0.5
            GreetTime = "Good morning"
       Case 0.5 To 0.71
            GreetTime = "Good afternoon"
       Case Else
            GreetTime = "Good evening"
 End Select

'Search for input box values and set fields to be pulled

lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "c").End(xlUp).Row
Set lookRng = Range("d1:d" & lr)
 valuefound = False
 For x = 1 To lr
   If Range("c" & x).Value = findStr Then
    Set foundCell = Range("B" & x).Offset(0, 4)
    Set foundcell1 = Range("e" & x).Offset(0, 1)
    Set foundcell2 = Range("B" & x).Offset(0, 5)
    valuefound = True
   End If
 Next x

'Ends the macro if input values to not match the sheet exactly

   If Not valuefound Then
    MsgBox "Is case-sensitive, Must be exact name", vbExclamation, "No     
 Match!"
    Exit Sub
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I would approach this is to query your table using SQL to exclude any duplicates (I adapted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19755396/performing-sql-queries-on-an-excel-table-within-a-workbook-with-vba-macro) example), then iterate over the returned recordset using a dictionary to store your approvers and their customers.

To get the below example to work I've added the Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library (for the SQL), and the Microsoft Scripting Runtime (for the dictionary), I believe it does what you need:

```
Sub GetApproversAndCustomers()
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

strFile = ThisWorkbook.FullName
strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strFile _
& ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

cn.Open strCon

'only retrieve unique combinations of approvers and customers
strSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT [Approver Name],[Customer Name] FROM [Sheet1$B1:E11]"

rs.Open strSQL, cn

Dim approvers As Dictionary
Set approvers = New Dictionary

Do Until rs.EOF
    'only add the approver to the collection if they do not already exist
    If approvers.Exists(rs.Fields("Approver Name").Value) = False Then
        'if they dont exist, add both the approver and customer to the dictionary
        approvers.Add rs.Fields("Approver Name").Value, rs.Fields("Customer Name").Value
    Else
        'if they do exist, find the approver and add the customer to the existing list
        approvers.Item(rs.Fields("Approver Name").Value) = approvers.Item(rs.Fields("Approver Name").Value) & ", " & rs.Fields("Customer Name").Value
    End If
    rs.MoveNext
Loop

'iterate over the dictionary, outputting our values
Dim strKey As Variant
For Each strKey In approvers.Keys()
    Debug.Print "Dear " & strKey & ", Your customer(s) " & approvers(strKey) & " all need to be reviewed."
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks very much, however, we do not have a dictionary and I need to install this on multiple users' machines (15 of them). Even though the people are named as customers, they are actually just random users who enter time, which we then need to approve. So, as that is constantly changing, I am not sure that creating a dictionary on everyone's machine will will work? I am new to this stuff though, and did try this code. It keeps erroring out at the rs.Open strSQL, cn line. The error is a run-time error, 'This table contains cells that are outside the range of cells defined in this spreadsheet'.

Comment: I do not actually know what that line means, so am not sure how to fix it, sorry!!

Comment: Did you add the references I mentioned? (In tools => references). you don't need to add them when deploying as you can use late binding.

Comment: Ah sorry I replied before your comment. I mocked up your spreadsheet and used the range of [Sheet1$B1:E11] is that the same as your range?

Comment: I did look at how cn is defined and I notice it says (in debug mode) that the userID is Admin, but that is not my user name, and most of the users would not be admins on their machines.  Not sure if that matters here?  Is there any way to get this to do what your code does WITHOUT the SQL dictionary?  I see your loop, was thinking something like, 'for each distinct Approver Name, pull unique Customer Name'?

Comment: Yep, I added the references, got both of them in.  That much I at least knew how to do, ha!  I changed the range in your code to match mine, set as c2:e9.

Comment: I don't think the admin thing would matter, can you test it? Yes a loop could be used instead of the sql (I would use Dictionaries with this approach too, using exists to remove duplicates), I just found the sql approach to be simpler.

Comment: Thanks, I just do not know how to test it or to change the user id?

Comment: Login as a non admin user? Or try it on a colleague?

Comment: Hi Majjam, please see above, I edited your post to add in pics of what I am seeing.  I am sorry, I do not know anything about SQL or how to correct this.  I have tried over and over, but do not seem to be able to get your code to work.  For what I suggested do you (or does anyone) have an idea of how to make it do that loop?  Thanks again!

Comment: Hi learningthisstuff, I looked at your images but again I dont think the admin thing will be a problem. I suspect it only refers to the default user used to query your workbook. Please test it as I mentioned to check. Also I wont be around for the next few days, but I've uploaded my version here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/k0zh6b3crquk0ef/Book1.xlsm?dl=0 just run the GetApproversAndCustomers method in the immediate window to run it.

Comment: One other thing, I know the sql approach may not be what you expected, but the language is incredibly useful and pretty straightforward to pick up, so it may be worth a look.

Comment: I've updated the dropbox version to be late bound so you don't have to add references to the scripting dictionary or the ADO library: https://www.dropbox.com/s/y8juxe4fvsgevu5/Book1.xlsm?dl=0 and regarding the dictionary, it only exists in memory for a short period of time so you can create them on your users computers without problem.

Comment: Hi Majjam, Thank you so much for your efforts, but the SQL approach is not working for us. I did as you said and tried this on different machines, with people logged in as Admin and it still did not work. We tried different combinations, but we get this same runtime error every time, saying that this table contains cells that are outside the range of cells defined this spreadsheet. We researched that error as well and could not find an answer. We formatted the data as a table as well, but still no joy.  We can be nothing but grateful to you, but need to re-post this question for VBA solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version that doesn't use SQL, I hope it works better than the previous one!

It loops over the table until there are no more rows with data in. It creates a dictionary of approvers and adds the corresponding customer (using the offset method) unless that customer has already been added.

```
Option Explicit

Public Function GetApproversAndCustomers2(ByVal approversColumn As String, ByVal customerNameColumn As String)
Dim approvers As Object
Set approvers = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

Dim iterator As Integer
iterator = 2

Do While Len(Sheet1.Range(approversColumn & iterator).Value) > 0
Dim approver As String
approver = Sheet1.Range(approversColumn & iterator).Value

If Not approvers.Exists(approver) Then
    If Len(approver) > 0 Then
        approvers.Add approver, Sheet1.Range(approversColumn & iterator).Offset(0, -2)
    End If
Else
    If InStr(1, approvers.Item(approver), Sheet1.Range(approversColumn & iterator).Offset(0, -2).Value) = 0 Then
        approvers.Item(approver) = approvers.Item(approver) & ", " & Sheet1.Range(approversColumn & iterator).Offset(0, -2).Value
    End If
End If
iterator = iterator + 1
Loop

iterator = 2

Dim key As Variant
For Each key In approvers.Keys
Debug.Print "Dear " & key & ", Your customer(s) " & approvers(key) & " all need to be reviewed."
Next
End Function
```

Comment: One other thing is that this answer is hard coded to Sheet2. You may need to update this.

Comment: Thank you, I changed the sheet name to Sheet2 just to match, but this code will not run either sadly.  It stops at the first "approversColumn", saying the variable is not defined.  Not sure how you are able to get it to work but we cannot.  We are using Excel 2016.  Thank you!

Comment: Did you call the method in the immediate window / the sheet with the parameters? Like ?GetApproversAndCustomers2("E", "C")

Comment: I launched the code from the VBA editor after clicking from the sheet (sheet2).  However, none of the columns have the label of 'approvers'.  I did try and re-name them to see if that would help, but still no joy.  I apologize that I cannot troubleshoot it, I am unfamiliar with some of this code and the relative task of creating a dictionary.

Comment: Hi Majjam, so as I continue to try to work through this, I did try to call this from the Immdiate Window.  I tried various options of the parameters (E, C, D, etc), but when I use "?GetApproversAndCustomers2("E", "C")" it errors out and says Compile Error:  Expected Function or variable".  Should  I have another function somewhere?

Comment: So I took out the parentheses.  If I add the ?, it just results in a C and D appearing under the macro name, spaced apart.  When I remove the ?, it errors out with compile error: Expected procedure, not variable.  What am I doing wrong?  THanks

Comment: please try it now

Comment: Okay, tried it again, same errors after pulling your new code.  I edited your answer to show you what I am seeing, to see if that will help.  Added two pics, one for when I ran it with the ?, then the other without the ?, which returns an error.  You have been way more than helpful, I completely understand if you wish to walk away from this mess!  =)

Comment: Ok, so if you create a totally new workbook and add your table, as it is shown in the question to sheet1, and then put the code in the answer (I've updated it to reference sheet1) into a module. Then this: ?GetApproversAndCustomers2("E", "C") executed in the immediate window, results in this for me: Dear Chris, Your customer(s) Thomas, Mark, Jared all need to be reviewed.
Dear John, Your customer(s) Denise all need to be reviewed.

Comment: And no problem! We'll get there :)

Comment: Hi Majjam, I did all that, copying in the new code to the module, created a new wkbk, sheet1, etc.  I still get the 'Sub or Function not defined' error if I click into the wkbk first, then hit enter on the immediate window.  However, if I click into the module first, then hit enter on the immediate window, I get no error, but it just enters down one blank line.  Tried on two other machines, same result.  All using win10 and Excel 2016.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I'm not sure what to suggest, I've just created the table as per your question in a new workbook (sheet1), copied the code into a new module and run ?GetApproversAndCustomers2("E","B") in the immediate window to get: Dear chris, Your customer(s) tom, mark, jared, denise all need to be reviewed.
Dear john, Your customer(s) tom all need to be reviewed.

Comment: Could you upload a screenshot of your vba environment and the references?