# Excel VBA finding duplicates, posting matching rows and search value

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates

I am working with a list of customer info searching for duplicates then pasting the entire row to a different sheet. My current code will find duplicates and paste them, however it will not paste the row being used for the search criteria.

[image: Example]

When I run my code it will copy row 3 to a different page, However I need it to also copy over row 1, to be able to see all "names" listed under the same "phone" not only the duplicate.

Here is my current code:

```
Option Explicit
Dim output As Worksheet
Dim data As Worksheet
Dim hold As Object
Dim celli
Dim nextRow

Sub main()
    Set output = Worksheets("phoneFlags")
    Set data = Worksheets("filteredData")
    Set hold = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For Each celli In data.Columns(3).Cells
        If Not hold.Exists(CStr(celli.Value)) Then
            If Not IsEmpty(celli.Value) Then
                hold.Add Key:="" & celli.Value, Item:=celli.Row
            End If
        ElseIf hold.Exists(CStr(celli.Value)) Then
            'Copies row to sheet
            data.Rows(celli.Row).Copy (output.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0))
        End If
    Next celli
End Sub
```

I've tried making a second `For Each` loop, but it returns the same result.

```
        ElseIf hold.Exists(CStr(celli.Value)) Then
        match = celli.Value
            For Each match In data.Columns(3).Cells
                data.Rows(celli.Row).Copy (output.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0))
            Next match
        End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid loops like the above, but rather use SQL

```
Option Explicit

Sub SQL()
    ' from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19755396/performing-sql-queries-on-an-excel-table-within-a-workbook-with-vba-macro
    ' by Joan-Diego Rodriguez

    ' get where we are and setup strings
    Dim strFile As String, strCon As String
    strFile = ThisWorkbook.FullName
    strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strFile _
        & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

    ' set up for ADO
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset, strSQL As String
    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    cn.Open strCon

    ' create SQL and open it
    strSQL = ""
    strSQL = strSQL & "SELECT * FROM [filteredData$] "
    strSQL = strSQL & "  Where PhoneNum In "
    strSQL = strSQL & "    (Select PhoneNum FROM [filteredData$] "
    strSQL = strSQL & "      Group By PhoneNum "
    strSQL = strSQL & "      Having Count(*) > 1"
    strSQL = strSQL & "     )"
    strSQL = strSQL & "   "   ' maybe have an order by here

    rs.Open strSQL, cn
    'Debug.Print rs.Name, rs.PhoneNum

    Dim nRow As Long
    nRow = 1
    Worksheets("phoneFlags").Activate
    Cells(nRow, "A") = "Name": Cells(nRow, "B") = "PhoneNum": Cells(nRow, "C") = "EMail"
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        nRow = nRow + 1
            Cells(nRow, "A") = rs.Fields(0): Cells(nRow, "B") = rs.Fields(1): Cells(nRow, "C") = rs.Fields(2)
        rs.movenext
    Loop

End Sub
```

While in View/Macros, on your top menu bar, where it sez File Edit View ...

Press TOOLS and then Press References

Scroll down to Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects, and select the last one with a check mark

...
Change this row which has new subscripts to (0) (1) (2)

Cells(nRow, "A") = rs.Fields(0): Cells(nRow, "B") = rs.Fields(1): Cells(nRow, "C") = rs.Fields(2)

Comment: I'm pretty new to the whole scripting thing, I haven't touched SQL so this is definitely outside of what I know how to do. I tried plugging it into my excel VBA however it returned most the information as `######`. The data I have isn't contained in a table, does it need to be for your script to work?

Comment: FROM [filteredData$]  gets the data from your sheet (suffixed by the dollar sign).  Your sheet should have column names in row 1, and the data should be in columns A, B, C, with PhoneNum being in column B. Tracing what is the problem may take a few iterations.  Scripting and VBA were new to you, and you began those ok; SQL makes some of that logic easier.  Please verify the worksheet contents and tell me more

Comment: I originally wasn't making the row 1 "Name" case sensitive, not the information is available, however it skips adding names to column A. It puts the phone numbers into column A, and the emails into column B.

Comment: Found the issue, this line of code `Cells(nRow, "A") = rs.Fields(1): ` needed to start at `rs.Fields(0)`. Now it's doing exactly what I wanted. I also wanted to be able to search for other criteria such as duplicate emails. Will it let me swap out `PhoneNum` to `EMail` when creating/opening the SQL to search for EMail duplicates?

Comment: Clone the SQL to become strSQL2, make changes to that, and then rs.Open strSQL2, cn   Try it, and learn.

Comment: Since this is a solution, click on the CheckMark near the top.   Did it work for EMail?

Answer (score 0):

if i understood your question i have an alternative code:

```
Sub test()
'control duplicate phone number. Execute macro in sheet1(active)

Dim rows, j, i, c, k As Integer
Dim swap As Variant

'in sheet where are all the data count number rows
rows = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count

c = 1 ' count rows number of the second sheet
For j = 1 To rows
    swap = Cells(j, 2) 'control the phone number
    For i = 1 To rows

        If (Cells(i, 2) = swap And i <> j) Then ' if find duplicate copy data into 2° sheet

            With Sheets("Sheet2")
                .Cells(c, 1) = Cells(j, 1) 'copy name
                .Cells(c, 2) = Cells(j, 2) 'copy phone number
                .Cells(c, 3) = Cells(j, 3) ' copy mail
                c = c + 1 'increment row of the second sheet
                i = rows 
            End With
        End If
    Next i
Next j
End Sub
```

i tried code and works fine.

Hope this helps.