# Dynamic Array of unique strings in VBA made from a ledger

Tags: excel, vba, stock, trading

I am starting to automate some of the tedious processes involved with my trading log (stocks/options). The current task that I would like to to automate is the creation and sorting of my stock cards. Basically, I create a 6x26 stock card that keeps track of certain stats for my trades on the ticker. The one thing that is holding me up is how to create a dynamic array of the stock tickers without their being repeat tickers. Also, it would be better if it was a struct.

Here is my current code:

```
Sub AutoUpdateCards()

    TickerCards.Activate
    Range("A1:ZZ1000").Clear

    tLog.Activate

    Dim tickers() As String
    Dim tSize As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim rngB As Range

    Set rngB = Range("$B2:$B1000")
    tSize = WorksheetFunction.SumProduct(1 / WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rngB, rngB))

    ReDim tickers(tSize)

    'store all unique tickers
    For i = 1 To tSize
        If i = 1 Then
           'store initial ticker
           tickers(i) = Range("B" & i)
        Else
            'compare with all of the currently stored tickers to make sure we aren't storing a duplicate
            For j = 1 To i

            Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```

I will then sort the array alphabetically for one update script, by total profit (for the ticker) in another script, by P/L...etc. This is why a dynamic struct would be better. Once the data is sorted I will traverse the array while inserting "stock" cards and formulas for each ticker. The Sheet is cleared before doing another update.

Comment: This sounds like it wants to be stored in a [`Dictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object) instead of an array.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19755396/performing-sql-queries-on-an-excel-table-within-a-workbook-with-vba-macro and use SQL...  Select DISTINCT ticker ...