# Where oh Where (VBA SQL Where Clause with Variable)

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I am SQL guy trying to help with a VBA project. I get a VBA error when I try to run this sql statement. Run-time error '-2147217913 (80040e07)' Automation error.

I can send a number without issue so I know I am doing something wrong when a string is passed. Thank you for your help! I have spent so much time trying to figure it out.

```vb
sSQLSting = "SELECT TOP 10 PctTtlAssets, Port_Code FROM [db_detail$] 
WHERE Port_Code  = ' " & [vbaThisPort] & " ' "
```

which looks like this when saved to my variable.

```vb
sSQLSting = "SELECT TOP 10 PctTtlAssets, Port_Code FROM [db_detail$] 
WHERE Port_Code  = 'salmemhs' "
```

Thank you

PS

Here is the full code the vba guy is using. Again, works fine until I send a string.

```vb
Sub sbADO()
Dim sSQLQry As String
Dim ReturnArray

Dim Conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim mrs As New ADODB.Recordset

Dim DBPath As String, sconnect As String, vbaThisPort As String


vbaThisPort = Trim(ThisWorkbook.Names("ThisPort").RefersToRange(1, 1))

'MsgBox (vbaThisPort) 'Testing

DBPath = ThisWorkbook.FullName

'You can provide the full path of your external file as shown below
'DBPath ="C:\InputData.xlsx"

sconnect = "Provider=MSDASQL.1;DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=" & DBPath & ";HDR=Yes';"

' Your SQL Statemnt (Table Name= Sheet Name=[DataSheet$])"

Conn.Open sconnect
    sSQLSting = "SELECT TOP 10 PctTtlAssets, Port_Code FROM [db_detail$] WHERE Port_Code  = '" & [vbaThisPort] & "'"

    mrs.Open sSQLSting, Conn
        '=>Load the Data into an array
        'ReturnArray = mrs.GetRows
                ''OR''
        '=>Paste the data into a sheet
        ActiveSheet.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset mrs
    'Close Recordset
    mrs.Close

'Close Connection
Conn.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Upon which line do you get the error?

Comment: Good question!     mrs.Open sSQLSting, Conn

Comment: Why not just open the file and read from the Sheet instead of using SQL?

Comment: Also, you may be having this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19755396/performing-sql-queries-on-an-excel-table-within-a-workbook-with-vba-macro where the SELECT FROM needs to be a SheetName!$Range for it to work properly. You have to convert the table name to a range, the post has an answer on how to do so.

Comment: The only thing that I can think of here (and I can't imagine it would throw an automation error) is that the ODBC driver is making assumptions about the column type. From experience it generally only looks at the top 10 (or so) records in the excel sheet and determines from there. If those top 10 rows are numeric it may decide this is a numeric row and it *may* throw an error when you filter by a string. I can't believe that it wouldn't just cast the row on the fly to do the FILTER but Jet and Ace have always been very fickle drivers.

Comment: JNevill is right about the column type being an issue. The first 100 rows for that column are integers. I deleted the rows to test, and it works perfectly now. I am going to see if there is a why I can define the column before it is imported in to Excel. Thank you JNevill and the others for your help!