# Is possible extract or delete worksheet from one closed workbook without open it?

Tags: excel, vba

I have two workbooks, one is for work (A) and the other only has usage data (B). File B has more than 25000 records and when I open it using VBA there is a long delay in loading.

One option I thought of was to delete the sheets with the data that I don't need but should delete them without opening the B file.

The second option would be to copy the data from the sheet without opening file B.

Currently, I am using Set wbOrigen = Workbooks.Open (FileName: = xxxxxx) but I need to speed up the load.

Is it possible to do any of this?

Comment: If you don't need the data then why save it in the file?

Comment: The other book has several sheets and some if I need it. If you could delete the sheet that contains so many records, the process would speed up to a 12:1 ratio.

Comment: You could try using SQL to query only the data you want - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19755396/performing-sql-queries-on-an-excel-table-within-a-workbook-with-vba-macro

Comment: It ist not possible to read from or write to a file which is not open. Excel uses DDE for some formulas like VLOOKUP() and PQ or SQL (like Tim Williams wrote) works also. It looks like you can read from closed files with those methods, but that ist not true. As I know there is no posibillity to delete whole tables in "closed" workbooks. About DDE: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/about-dynamic-data-exchange?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: Thanks to both.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it is not possible to access a Workbook's data without opening it. But from my experience this is not a problem (as this is very fast) as long as you remember to close it in the end.
The "standard" trick to improve performance is to disable ScreenUpdating and Events like such:

```vb
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
' Open Workbook, Load data, do some operations, close Workbook
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks but I already using those declarations, that is not the problem.

```vb
Public Sub TLD_StartMacro()
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = Excel.xlCalculationManual
        .EnableEvents = False
        ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False
        .CutCopyMode = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
    End With
End Sub

Public Sub TLD_EndMacro()
    
    With Application
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = Excel.xlAutomatic
        .EnableEvents = True
        .CutCopyMode = False     ' Esta sentencia vacía el portapapeles
    End With
End Sub
```