# VBA code equivalent to "SELECT * FROM [query] where [column] = combobox

Tags: excel, vba

I have a data connection in my xlsm file, which is called "DATA".
I created my combo box and input the value from a range.

Now I need to return a result set based on the value from the combo box (drop down list). e.g. if the value in the dropdown list is "CompanyXYZ", then my query from "DATA" needs to be returned but only the data for CompanyXYZ.

The sql equivalent is:

```
"SELECT * FROM [query] where [column] = combobox
```

**Issue #1**
Below is my sheet("DATA"). It has a table returned by the SQL query. One of the columns is Debtor_Name. It has more than 8500 rows but only 90 are unique.
[image]

In my other sheet, I have an ActiveX ComboBox that needs to return all the unique values from DATA.Debtor_name column (the 90 unique values).
[image]

Sample VBA for issue #1:

```vb
Sub Populate_Combobox_Worksheet()
'The Excel workbook and worksheets that contain the data, as well as the range placed on that data
Dim wbBook As Workbook
Dim wsSheet As Worksheet
Dim rnData As Range

'Variant to contain the data to be placed in the combo box.
Dim vaData As Variant

'Initialize the Excel objects
Set wbBook = ThisWorkbook
Set wsSheet = wbBook.Worksheets("DATA")

'Set the range equal to the data, and then (temporarily) copy the unique values of that data to the L column.
With wsSheet
    Set rnData = .Range(.Range("D1"), .Range("D10000").End(xlUp))
    rnData.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
                      CopyToRange:=.Range("X1"), _
                      Unique:=True
    'store the unique values in vaData
    vaData = .Range(.Range("X2"), .Range("X10000").End(xlUp)).Value
    'clean up the contents of the temporary data storage
    .Range(.Range("X1"), .Range("X10000").End(xlUp)).ClearContents
End With

'display the unique values in vaData in the combo box already in existence on the worksheet.
With wsSheet.OLEObjects("ComboBox1").Object
    .Clear
    .List = vaData
    .ListIndex = -1
End With
End Sub
```

**Issue #2.**
Now the end user will need to select a debtor_name from the combo box, then click on refresh data. This DATA REFRESH will need to only pull the data from SQL where debtor_name = [selected value in combo box]

---

I asked about  for issue #2 because I did not know I had an issue with my combo box (issue #1); however, I can handle that somehow; only need help with issue #2 now.

Comment: Please provide some data for testing. It seems use for loop to achieve your goal but it is necessary to know your how many columns that contains data.  The another method should be using SQL in VBA

Comment: Hi @GGG thanks for your reply. I have added more info on the question. thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: You can do what you want with ADODB.  Read this question and answers and see if it points you in the right direction.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19755396/performing-sql-queries-on-an-excel-table-within-a-workbook-with-vba-macro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SQL to populate the ComboBox with unique values.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Populate_Combobox_Worksheet()
    Dim con As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset, SQL As String
    Set con = GetConnection

    ' query
    SQL = " SELECT DISTINCT [Debtor_name] FROM [DATA$]" & _
          " WHERE [Debtor_name] IS NOT NULL" & _
          " ORDER BY [Debtor_Name]"

    Set rs = con.Execute(SQL)
    With Sheet2.ComboBox1
        .Clear
        .List = Application.Transpose(rs.GetRows)
        .ListIndex = -1
    End With
    con.Close
End Sub

Sub RefreshData()
    Dim con As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset, SQL As String
    Set con = GetConnection

    ' query
    SQL = " SELECT * FROM [DATA$]" & _
          " WHERE [Debtor_name] = '" & Sheet2.ComboBox1.Value & "'"
    Set rs = con.Execute(SQL)
    Sheet2.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs
    con.Close
End Sub

Function GetConnection() As ADODB.Connection
    Dim wb As Workbook, sCon As String
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    sCon = "Data Source=" & wb.FullName & "; " & _
           "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;"";"
   
    ' connect
    Set GetConnection = New ADODB.Connection
    With GetConnection
        .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
        .ConnectionString = sCon
        .Open
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks @CDP1802 , Checking it now.