# How to Get Data on Close Workbook Table on Excel VBA without Openning It?

Tags: excel, vba

I have **three** Workbook,

- **First** is for my ***Inventory System for Admin***,
- **Second** is my ***Inventory System for Employees***, and
- **Third** is my ***Database***.

Does anyone know how to get `Data Table` on ***Database*** without Opening it and put it either in Admin or Employee's Inventory System?

Comment: What's wrong with opening it using `Workbooks.Open`? Or using an approach similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19755396/performing-sql-queries-on-an-excel-table-within-a-workbook-with-vba-macro)?

Comment: You can query the data as a recordset using ADO - eg.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19755396/performing-sql-queries-on-an-excel-table-within-a-workbook-with-vba-macro

Comment: Is PowerQuery an option for you. It's pretty good for stuff like this and unlikely you'll need any coding within your query as it should recognise them table.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is go to **"Data" tab in ribbon > Get Data > From File > From Workbook**. Then open the "Database" excel file.

This will allows you to preview the data from the "Database" sheet. If you don't need to make any changes you can click load directly and the data will be copied.

- You can check out [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0aeZX1l4JT4) for more examples on how to use Power query.
- I also recommend checking out [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6lBqYInBldk) on how Power Query can help you.