# Excel Jet Access, Use named range as where clause

Tags: excel, ms-access, jet

I have a query I use in excel to get some data from a database.

In a sheet I have a named range, how can I use a named range as part of my "where" clause in my query?

I am trying to query where clause `Position` with a large set of data I have in another sheet in a named range.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT endOfDay,position,M.Name, M.SetName ,sum(M.Value) as Value
FROM Common.View M 
WHERE (endOfDay ={ts '2019-01-31 23:59:59'} or endOfDay ={ts '2019-01-31 23:59:59'} ) 
AND M.isHoliday=0 
GROUP BY endOfDay,position,M.Name, M.SetName
```

I have tried doing :

`and position = [named range]`
also `and position = [Sheet1$B2:B200]` but do not work.

sample data in my named range:

```
+----------+
| 'stack', |
| 'over',  |
| 'flow'   |
+----------+
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I run SQL statements on a named range within an excel sheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914980/how-can-i-run-sql-statements-on-a-named-range-within-an-excel-sheet)