# Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object Sheet - ACE OLEDB

Tags: excel, vba, adodb

I'm trying to copy values from one workbook into another. The code below used to work. However, after making required updates (I'm on my work laptop, so don't really have a choice) to my Office, the connection to ADO in my macro no longer works.

This is the error I get:

```
Run-time error '-2147217865 (800040e37)':

The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object 'CustomSheetName1$'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly. If 'CustomSheetName1$' is not a local object, check your network connection or contact the server administrator.
```

I'm using Excel for Microsoft 365 MSO (16.0.13530.20368) 64-bit

The code breaks in the last line:

```
Public Sub GetData(sourceFile As Variant, SourceSheet As String, _
                   SourceRange As String, TargetRange As Range, _
                   Header As Boolean, UseHeaderRow As Boolean, _
                   pickUpZip As String, _
                   dropOffZip As String, logSheet As Worksheet, _
                   monthString As String)

Dim rsCon As Object
Dim rsData As Object
Dim szConnect As String
Dim szSQL As String
Dim lCount As Long
Dim lastLgRow As Integer

If Header = False Then
    If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
        szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                    "Data Source=" & sourceFile & ";" & _
                    "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=No"";"
    Else
        szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                    "Data Source=" & sourceFile & ";" & _
                    "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=No"";"
    End If
Else
    If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
        szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                    "Data Source=" & sourceFile & ";" & _
                    "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes"";"
    Else
        szConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                    "Data Source=" & sourceFile & ";" & _
                    "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes"";"
    End If
End If

If SourceSheet = "" Then
    szSQL = "SELECT * FROM " & SourceRange$ & ";"
Else
    szSQL = "SELECT * FROM [" & SourceSheet$ & "$]" 
    szSQL = szSQL & " WHERE [Pickup Zip] LIKE '" & pickUpZip & "%'" & _
            " AND [Drop Off Zip] LIKE '" & dropOffZip & "%" & "';"
End If


Set rsCon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rsData = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

rsCon.Open szConnect
rsData.Open szSQL, rsCon, 0, 1, 1
```

I saw some people having similar issues when in their queries they specified a range of cells. However, this is not the case here, as I want to query the entire 'CustomSheetName1' spreadsheet.

Any ideas?

Comment: `SourceRange` what containt this variable ? Provide example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I run SQL statements on a named range within an excel sheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914980/how-can-i-run-sql-statements-on-a-named-range-within-an-excel-sheet)

Comment: SourceRange is not even used, that line of code is not even executed in the IF..ELSE statement.

Comment: ??? `If SourceSheet = "" Then
    szSQL = "SELECT * FROM " & SourceRange$ & ";"
Else`

Comment: SourceSheet is never empty. IF statement skips to ELSE there.

Comment: This is how the SourceRange is defined: "A2:X"
Like I said, that piece of code is never executed

Comment: As I said in my answer I suppose that you have excess $ sign in yours `FROM [" & SourceSheet$ & "$]" ` and I think that this should look like  `FROM [" & SourceSheet & "$];" `

Answer (score 0):

I'm not well VBA coder but here:

```
If SourceSheet = "" Then
    szSQL = "SELECT * FROM " & SourceRange$ & ";"
Else
    szSQL = "SELECT * FROM [" & SourceSheet$ & "$]"
```

should'nt this look like:

```
If SourceSheet = "" Then
    szSQL = "SELECT * FROM [" & SourceRange & "$];"
Else
    szSQL = "SELECT * FROM [" & SourceSheet & "$];"
```

?

Btw. I'm not sure what you want to do with `SourceRange` in place of `SourceSheet`

Comment: No, I don't think this is the cause. Like I said, the code below DID work before the updates. I suspect the error has something to do with references. Perhaps I'm not referencing the correct library version but I can't fix what I do not know is broken.