# How to dynamically fetch data to combo box

Tags: excel, vba

I am not able to fetch data to Drop down based on Drop down 1

[image: MY GUI]

**Drop down 1** -> will fetch NAME Details

**Drop down 2** -> will fetch AGE Details

**Drop down 3** -> will fetch COURSE Details

How i am trying to fetch data is

if Dropdown 1 -> I selected value : `A` then the value for Dropdown 2 should fetch automatically and Dropdown 3 as well

**Dropdown 2 will have below values**

```
12
13
17
22
21
19
```

**And Dropdown 3 should fetch values**

```
MCA
MBA
MMS
BAF
BMS
BBM
```

And if I select Dropdown 1 -> Value -> `B` the Dropdown 2 and Dropdown 3 should fetch values automatically

So on selecting `Dropdown 1 -> B` , below values should be populated for *Dropdown 2* and *Dropdown 3* automatically

And Dropdown 2 should fetch values

```
25
45
2
20
```

And Dropdown 3 should fetch values

```
MBBS
CDAC
DD
SF
```

**I have tried this code but not working ? I am new to vba coding**

```
Private Sub cmbabc()
Me.cmbabc.Clear

Dim sh = As Worksheet 
Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim i As Long
For i=2 To sh.Range("A1000").End(xlUp).Row
If sh.Cells(i,1)= Me.cmbabc.value Then
If Application.WorksheetFunction.Count if (sh.Range("B2","B" & i), sh.Cells(i,2) =1 Then
Me.Worksheet.AddItem sh.Cells(i,2)
End if 

End if 

Next i

End Sub
```

Data in my excel sheet 1 is below

[image: Data in excel sheet 1]

Comment: Is dropdown 3 to be changed on selecting from drop-down 2 (and vice-versa) ?

Comment: @Tim Williams   yes on selection of dropdown 2 -> dropdown 3 should populate values in that column what ever values are their

Comment: When posting sample data, make it easy for us: post it as **text**

Answer (score 0):

If your Combobox's are named as cmbAbc for NAME, cmbAge for AGE, cmbCourse for COURSE, we can use Excel VBA query capacity with ADODB.Recordset as follows:

```
' query Excel sheet:
'
' strColumnName: Excel column name to query
' strWhere: where string
' xarr: array to return and then used as ComboBox list
'
Function queryExcel4ColumName(ByVal strColumnName, ByVal strWhere)
  Dim lLastRow As Long
  Dim strRange

  Dim strCon As String, strFile As String, strSQL As String
  Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
  Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
  Dim i As Long, xarr

  strFile = ThisWorkbook.FullName
  strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & strFile _
    & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

  Set cnn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
  Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

  cnn.Open strCon

'
  lLastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
  strRange = "Sheet1$A1:C" & lLastRow

' query a Range:
  strSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT " & strColumnName _
    & " FROM [" & strRange & "]"

' add WHERE clause if not null:
  If (strWhere <> "") Then
    strSQL = strSQL _
      & " WHERE " & strWhere
  End If

  rst.Open strSQL, cnn

  i = 0
  While (Not rst.EOF)
    If (i = 0) Then
      ReDim xarr(i)
    Else
      ReDim Preserve xarr(i)
    End If
    xarr(i) = rst(0).Value
    rst.MoveNext
    i = i + 1
  Wend

  rst.Close
  Set rst = Nothing
  Set cnn = Nothing
  queryExcel4ColumName = xarr
End Function

Private Sub cmbAbc_Change()
  Me.cmbAge.List = queryExcel4ColumName("AGE", "NAME='" & Me.cmbAbc.Value & "'")
  Me.cmbCourse.List = queryExcel4ColumName("COURSE", "NAME='" & Me.cmbAbc.Value & "'")
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
  Me.cmbAbc.List = queryExcel4ColumName("NAME", "")
End Sub
```

This code is all in the UserForm1 Private Module. When UserForm_Initialize(),
we load all distinct names from the used range in Sheet1.

In Sheet1, we used the row 1 as column names, they are [NAME], [AGE] and [COURSE].

When cmbAbc_Change(), we load corresponding distinct AGEs and COURSEs for cmbAge and cmbCourse respectively.

[image]

[image]

Please also consult https://stackoverflow.com/a/915297/953097 .